# Error on Python strip( ) function

Tags: python, python-2.7, strip

In my script below

```
def main():
    file= open("NCSIDS_ObsExp.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
        line= line.split(',')
        print line
    file.close()
main()
```

I get:

```
['Ashe', '1853282.679', '1673876.66', '1 ', '2 \n']
['Alleghany', '1963178.059', '1695301.229', '0 ', '1 \n']
```

How do i get rid of the `\n`? I am very confused with the strip() function. I am getting an error.

```
def main():
    file= open("NCSIDS_ObsExp.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
        line= line.split(',')
        append= line.strip('n')
        print line
    file.close()
main()
```

Comment: In the future, you might want to include the specific error message to make it easier to solve the question.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `line.strip().split(',')`, which will strip the `\n` from the line during iteration. Also, it is usually better to open files with `with` where possible. This is a context manager that ensures that the file is properly closed when you exit the indented block:

```
In [1]: with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         print line.strip().split(',')
   ...:         
   ...:         
['one']
['two', ' three']
['four', 'five', 'six']
```

The issue is that when you read a line, the `\n` character is interpreted as part of that line, and when you `split` it is picking up the newline in the last item:

```
In [2]: with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         print line.split(',')
   ...:         
   ...:                
['one\n']
['two', ' three\n']
['four', 'five', 'six\n']
```

Therefore in order to get rid of it, you can run `strip()` on the line itself, which will remove the character from the end of the line, letting you split as you expect.

Your error (in the second block) comes from this:

```
line= line.split(',')
append= line.strip('n')
```

You are splitting the line on the comma, which returns a list. However you are then trying to strip the list, which will cause an `AttributeError` because lists do not have a `strip` method. Also, `\n` is a special character that indicates a new line, so stripping just `n` will not have the effect you want - you need to strip the entire `\n` character. You can see its 'special' nature if you try to `print` a string containing the character:

```
In [1]: s = 'A\nnew\nline'

In [2]: s
Out[2]: 'A\nnew\nline'

In [3]: print s
A
new
line

In [4]: s.strip('n')
Out[4]: 'A\nnew\nline'
```

Comment: Also note that line.strip('n') is incorrect. You probably want line.strip('\n')

Comment: @vkontori True true, will update to point that out more explicitly.